# NextJS returns _error page on server but login page on client?

Tags: next.js

I've got a strange issue, and honestly have no idea where to even begin looking.

I have a NextJS app with a GraphQL endpoint built into the pages/api section. It's still pretty basic, I mostly just have login/register functionality built out.

I noticed an issue where my currentUser query was being run on pages that should not be running it (like /login and /register). What I discovered is that on my Page component wrapper is that the _error route is being triggered for some reason, even though it's not displaying that client-side. This component simply wraps the main  in _app.tsx.

Here's the Page component wrapper:

```ts
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
// third-party
import React, { ReactChild, ReactChildren } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { AnimateSharedLayout } from 'framer-motion';

// custom components
import CustomDrawer from 'components/common/Drawer';
import Navbar from 'components/common/Navbar';

// styles
import CommonPageStyles from './CommonPageStyles';

interface AuxProps {
  children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
}

const Page: React.FC = ({ children }: AuxProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.route);
  const isLoggedOut =
    router.route === '/_error' || // temporary fix
    router.route === '/login' ||
    router.route === '/register' ||
    router.route === '/terms-and-conditions';

  const isOnboarding = router.route === '/onboarding';

  const renderPage = () => {
    console.log({ isLoggedOut });
    console.log({ isOnboarding });

    if (isLoggedOut && !isOnboarding) {
      return (
        <div style={{ padding: '0', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!isLoggedOut && isOnboarding) {
      return (
        <div style={{ padding: '64px 0 0 0', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
          <Navbar simple />
          {children}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="page-container">
          <Navbar />
          <CustomDrawer />
          <div className="inner-wrap">{children}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <AnimateSharedLayout>
      <CommonPageStyles>{renderPage()}</CommonPageStyles>
    </AnimateSharedLayout>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

I have three console logs placed in this component: one for `router.route`, and one for my custom variables `isLoggedIn` and `isOnboarding`. When I refresh the /login page, here is what I see on my server:

```
/login
{ isLoggedOut: true }
{ isOnboarding: false }
/_error
{ isLoggedOut: true }
{ isOnboarding: false }
```

but the client is rendering the Login page just as normal.

So I built a crude custom _error page to try and debug this:

```tsx
function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : 'An error occurred on client'}
    </p>
  );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  console.log({ statusCode });
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Error;
```

and now I see this on the server:

```
{ isLoggedOut: true }
{ isOnboarding: false }
event - build page: /_error
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
{ statusCode: 404 }
/_error
{ isLoggedOut: true }
{ isOnboarding: false }
```

As you can see the error statusCode that is being returned is a 404, but I have no idea why! Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I'd forgotten that I had installed the `next-pwa` package when initially building out this project. This generates a manifest.json, which is referenced in the  of _document.tsx. This file was not being built, resulting in a 404. I simply removed this package and any references to it, which appears to have fixed the issue!